# captions not appearing below subfigure

Tags: captions, subfloats, subcaption

Code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,array,graphicx,float,caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{initial_normal.eps}
        \caption{Normal Distribution}
        \label{fig1a}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}[H]
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{initial_uniform.eps}
        \caption{Uniform Distribution}
        \label{fig1b}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{distributions}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The captions should come below the figure but I am getting them to the right of the figures and the caption text is aligned centrally with respect to the page instead of the subfigure.
Am I making a mistake here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not put `[H]` after `\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}[H]` Further, these points may be noted:

1. Don't put a blank line in between the subfigures.
2. The sum of `width`s of two `subfigure` should not exceed `\textwidth`
3. Put a `%` after the first `subfigure` if you specify a width of `0.5\textwidth` for both `subfigures`. If the sum is less than `\textwidth`, you may put a `\hfill` in between.

Now your code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn,11pt,a4paper,demo]{article}
\usepackage{geometry,array,graphicx,float,caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
%    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{initial_normal.eps}
        \caption{Normal Distribution}
        \label{fig1a}
    \end{subfigure}%   %% This % is needed when you use 0.5\textwidth
    %  Don't leave the blank line
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}%[H]   %% Don't put this here
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=6cm]{initial_uniform.eps}
        \caption{Uniform Distribution}
        \label{fig1b}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

May be the `subcaption` package manual is useful here. You can access it by typing `texdoc subcaption` from command line/prompt. The correct usage for `subfigure` is

```
\begin{subfigure}[<pos>]{<width>}

... content like \includegraphics and caption

\end{subfigure}
```

Here `<pos>` is `t` or `b` `c` (default). Both `[<pos>]{<width>}` are same as that for a `minipage`.

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: See even in your case the the subfigure caption is not directly below the subfigure.. Mine is worse still; I am not getting the neat composite figure as shown in all the examples. No difference in my code!!

Comment: @bharat_iyengar Where do you want the caption? Both figure and caption centered or left aligned?

Comment: Figures side by side and their captions centrally aligned with respect to the subfigure (not the page). Just like [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats)

Comment: thanks harish.. i made an edit.. the captions are still not quite in their position. And what is the logic of putting a `%` after `\end{subfigure}`

Comment: @bharat_iyengar Put `\centering`s as in my answer. But there shouldn't be any overlap! Again clueless! :(  `%` after the `\end{subfigure}` cancels `end of line space`.

Comment: fixed it.. It was a problem in the EPS file.. Thanks